# How to scroll a div when parent & html tags are set to overflow:hidden?

Tags: css

I'm wondering what is the proper way to scroll a div when both the parent and html tags are set to `overflow: hidden;`.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgGmQ/61/).

Comment: You can click with your mouse wheel, and then move the mouse. But this is not related to programming.

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't work with a touchpad.

Comment: The right one option is to remove `overflow: hidden` from `html`. Don't forget to user without mouse(wheel). Smartphones will have the same problem.

Comment: This is a simplified example, but the `overflow: hidden` on `html` is necessary.

Comment: Looks like you're also missing the width/height on the 'body' in order for the 'overflow-y: scroll;' to work - trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/btvq95vv/ ?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention you'll need to work with html > body > div, each respective parent needs the set width and height to inherit properly and for overflow to work accordingly.